# google api- google sign in for website, cannot access the basic profile

Tags: html, jsp, google-api, google-signin

I want to get the users' profile, like user id and email address, i have tried many ways to do it, but still get the error of "TypeError: googleUser.getBasicProfile is not a function"

I follow the instruction of google document, but i still get the error:

[image]

and here is all code of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>googleSignin</title>
    <meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="https://schema.org/AddAction" />
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="589020135825-sbg93psr9i0v8gq6ajm7mv9et38o9ts2.apps.googleusercontent.com">

</head>


<body>



<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" onclick="onSignIn('googleUser')"></div>

<script>'


    function onSignIn(googleUser) {


        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        var user_name = profile.getName();
        alter(user_name);

        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        //The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        //var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        //console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

    }

    function signOut(){
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function() {
           console.log('User signed out!');
        });
    }

    function onLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init();
            auth2.then(function(){
               //current values
                var isSignedIn = auth2.isSignedIn.get();
                var currentUser = auth2.currentUser.get();

                if (!isSignedIn) {
                    //rendering it
                    gapi.signin2.render('google-signin-button', {
                        'onsuccess': 'onSignIn'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }

 </script>
 <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is all code of it:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing your code to the example you don't need the onclick handler in your button div. The parementer you pass via that is a string giving the error. Let platform.js sort out the calling

You might want to add asunc defer to you script as well

see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/